# gzip compression is enabled but not working

Tags: performance, gzip

I have checked gzip compression in the following site  http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test it shows

```
https://domain.com/ is Compressed
Uncompressed Page Size: 108.1 KB
Compressed Page Size: 22.9 KB
Savings: 78.8%
```

But http://gtmetrix.com/ says

There are 25 plain text components that should be sent compressed, any idea

Comment: can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual webpage this is just guessing, but most likely the webserver is configured to serve HTML pages with GZIP compression but it's not configured to send other types with GZIP compression.

When configuring GZIP compression in webservers, you want to make sure that all types that are not already compressed by it's file format have GZIP compression enabled.

This means you want to enable GZIP compression for all text based responses: html, but also css, javascript, json, XML files, rss, etc.
But also some non-text files like favicon ico files and most web font-face files(except woff)

You must not enable GZIP compression for files that are already compressed by their file format. That means most images, videos and audio.

For an example you can check out the [htaccess of the html5 boilerplate project](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess).